# Which are the necessary files to execute Solr in a remote host and how to configure the security (permissions, etc)?

Tags: solr

I have a database (mysql) at localhost. I use Solr to index and make queries, it works fine.
Now I want to put the Solr index on a remote host. I know that I must have the permission to run java and ssh access. But I must admit that, even though I can make Solr work, I don't understand very well each file that are part of Solr.
So what I want to know is which are the files estrictly necessary to make Solr index work to make queries? data files? yes, but what else? And how should I configure the permissions? read only? execute? And... I guess that there are another security items I must pay attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you have to install at least a web-container (e.g. Tomcat or Jetty) and deploy the solr-[version].war file onto it. 
For security reasons you can restrict the access to the Server via web-interface in the configuration of this web-container.

Beneath that solr needs a home-directory in which Solr stores its index and configuration. I think this must have rw permissions since Solr changes the index on import and maintains index-usage-information.

Comment: My index folder's the following url: **public_html/apache-solr-3.5.0/example/example-DIH/solr/db/data/index/** As far as I see I must copy this folder, wich contains the index itself. You say that **index/** should have rw permission... but what happens w/ the rest of the fls (java fls and config. fls)? And on the other hand I guess that inside **apache-solr-3.5.0/** there're many files that I don't need, but I can't say wich of them are dispensable. And finally, how should I update my index? by overwriting the old index files and restarting Solr? I know it works, but I think it is a bit raw.

Comment: I know there are many questions... but I'm very ignorant... sorry. I have already read the documentation but couldn't find the information I need. Perhaps it is there and someone could tell me where.

Comment: The essential files for Solr are in the folder **example/solr/*** this folder is called solr-home and you have to configure it in your web-container (see [link](http://crazorsharp.blogspot.de/2010/01/full-text-search-using-solr-lucene-and.html) for an windows example).

You can update your index via the [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) the index will usally resist in the **data**-directory in Solr home.